# Ubuntu Preseed file for RAID 1 without LVM

Tags: ubuntu, raid, preseed

I'm trying to use Ubuntu's Preseed file to install ubuntu with RAID 1 with no LVM.

Basically I want */dev/sda* and */dev/sdb* to be in RAID, no home and swap partition is needed.

This is what I tried:

```
d-i partman-auto/method string raid
d-i partman-auto/disk string /dev/sda /dev/sdb

d-i partman-auto/expert_recipe string \
      multiraid ::                                   \
          1000 5000  raid                            \
                  $primary{ } method{ raid }  $bootable{ } format{ } \
          .                                          \

d-i partman-auto-raid/recipe string \
1 2 0 ext3 /                        \
      /dev/sda1#/dev/sdb1           \
.

d-i partman-md/confirm boolean true
d-i partman-partitioning/confirm_write_new_label boolean true
d-i partman/choose_partition select finish
d-i partman/confirm boolean true
d-i partman/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true
d-i partman-basicfilesystems/no_swap boolean false
```

And this fails with the syslog being: http://pastebin.com/XaTkiJSZ

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fixed it myself, was a small syntax error. (an extra backspace, where is was not required).

I also added some missing parameters.

This is for anyone who wants to have only a root directory (no swap, home) with RAID 1.

```
# Disk Partitioning
d-i partman-auto/method string raid
d-i partman-auto/disk string /dev/sda /dev/sdb

d-i partman-auto/expert_recipe string                                    \
      multiraid ::                                                       \
              1000 5000 -1 raid                                          \
                      $primary{ } method{ raid }  $bootable{ } format{ } \
          .

d-i partman-auto-raid/recipe string \
    1 2 0 ext3 /                    \
          /dev/sda1#/dev/sdb1       \
.

d-i partman-md/confirm boolean true
d-i partman-md/device_remove_md boolean true
d-i partman-md/confirm_nooverwrite  boolean true
d-i partman-partitioning/confirm_write_new_label boolean true
d-i partman/choose_partition select finish
d-i partman/confirm boolean true
d-i partman/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true
d-i partman-basicfilesystems/no_swap boolean false
```